# Long hyperlinks in questions bleeding over, Eeeek!

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492946/facebook-like-button-breaks-ssl-because-of-the-image-sprite-loaded) has a really long hyperlink in it and it takes over the page.

[image: Eeek hyperlink bleeds why???]

EDIT
Here's an exact copy of the link in question:

- https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=110658975693059&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com&send=false&layout=button_count&width=280&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=dark&font&height=21

Comment: Is that... is that a freehand unicorn? If you traced it, cool, but if it's freehand, __hats off to you, sir or madam__.

Comment: Browser info? No repro on Win7 FF 3.6.18.

Comment: Win7/Chrome version 9999 or whatever the latest is (13 today). Also happens on Win7/IE9.

Comment: Repro Win7 x64/Chrome 10 (my work proxy keeps it from updating, YAY)

Comment: What do unicorns have to do with extra long links included in the post body?

Comment: @random If you have to ask, we can't possibly express it in a way that would help you understand the connection.  I suggest meditating.

Comment: @Adam Davis - thanks for teaching me that "EEEEEK" has 5 E's. I wasn't entirely sure and guessed wrong. A case of RTFM for me, sorry.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-declined] coming in 3..2...1...

Comment: @Off Actually, I could be wrong.  According to the meme page, it should be four: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/83625#83625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I have put in a fix. We had `word-wrap:break-word;` on <p> only, now I've applied it to the whole post body text.</s>

This fix caused [more problems than it solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96700), so it's backed out for now; we'll add a better fix.

Comment: @TomWij the fix is on dev. it will be in the next production build. (later tonight EST most likely)

Comment: I think this change makes code blocks wrap very ugly in Webkit browsers. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 8):

Please add your results if they are not already shown below:

**Firefox** - OK

- [NO REPRO](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/4e17f25d-4e7b-4a58-b6a3-dddf30ffaa4d/2011-06-27_1927.png) - 7.0a1 - 2011-06-20 - Windows 7 x64
- NO REPRO - 5.0 - Windows 7
- NO REPRO - 4.0.1 - Windows 7 x64, Linux (Iceweasel)
- NO REPRO - 3.6.18 - Windows 7

**Chrome** - BAD

- [REPRO](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/720b6030-9c50-4dea-97e5-8f57b31ed0b0/2011-06-27_1935.png) - 14.0.797.0 dev - Windows 7 x64
- REPRO - 13 - Windows 7, Linux
- [REPRO](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/0c23cbf3-2e7b-4634-b05c-e26b9bfd99e1/2011-06-27_1928.png) - 12.0.742.5 dev - Windows 7 x64
- [REPRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMYln.png) - 10 - Windows 7 x64
- [REPRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqz0p.png) - 12.0.742.100 - Ubuntu 10.10 x86

**IE** - BAD

- [REPRO](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/4ed5bdd2-9cc1-4b8b-b0e8-2a9d5338b033/2011-06-27_1930.png) - 9.0 - Windows 7
- [REPRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qWNO.png) - 8.0 - Windows 7

**Safari** - BAD

- [REPRO](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/71c7bc6b-7ac9-432f-97f3-a85b498d44d4/2011-06-27_1938.png) - 5.0.5 (7533.21.1) - Windows 7 x64
- [REPRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ39n.png) - 5.0.5 (6533.21.1) - Mac OS X 10.6
- REPRO - Mobile Safari iPhone iOS 5.0 beta 2

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the cleanup and better format!

Answer (score 6):

This can be fixed **in most browsers** by applying a wrapping class to links that exceed the post width:

```
.force-wrap
{
    white-space:
        pre-wrap,
        -moz-pre-wrap !important,
        -pre-wrap, -o-pre-wrap;

    word-wrap:
        break-word;
 }
```

Specific browser fixes:

1. Chrome: CSS 3: `pre-wrap`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop
2. FF < 3.5: `-moz-pre-wrap !important`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space
3. Opera: `-pre-wrap, -o-pre-wrap;`: No specific official reference, often mentioned.
4. IE 9: `break-word`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531184.aspx

What I see:

1. Firefox: Still not occurring.
2. Google Chrome: No longer occurring.
3. Opera: No longer occurring.
4. Internet Explorer 9: Still occurring, has been reduced as one split does takes place...

Answer (score 2):

This could also be fixed by not pasting in whopping great big raw URL's such as that one.

Sometimes a raw url is fine, but it's better to hide under a "fancier link" (as the help calls it) with a sensible textual description about what is being linked to:

```
- [link to something of interest](http://myreally.big.url/....)
```

Comment: Perhaps we could reject posts that have links of X subsequent characters with a warning?

Comment: @AdamDavis: To what would it convert the link?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I read *"reject posts"* and thought of autoconverting them instead, using the format of this answer.  I'm somewhere around 13-14 steps away from what I'm reading apparently.  Anyway, ignore the ravings of this madman.