# Chrome bug with code blocks

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is a bug in the **Google Chrome** browser (I'm running `14.0.803.0 dev`), where code blocks **wrap text**, and it is very annoying:

[image: annoying text wrap]

Fortunately, I have a fix for you! Just add this to your CSS:

```
pre {
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: Eh, if that horizontal scrollbar shows in your code blocks you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Won't, it seems half the [tag:ios] questions with code in them are 100+ characters wide. `NSIGuessThatIsTheDownside: OfReallyLongParameterizedArguments`.

Comment: @sarnold: dunno how they handle line breaks in that language.  Most languages allow continuation on the next line via some token (newline, underscore, etc)....

Comment: @Won't, it's true that it _could_ be written that way; but after a level or two of indentation, it's hard to fit both the name and parameter on the same line and still fit in 80 columns. I don't know how they read their code without going crazy. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96597/long-hyperlinks-in-questions-bleeding-over-eeeek/96617#96617) didn't have quite the expected effects. Backed out for now; overflowing links aren't half as bad (as they are a rare edge case, unlike codeblocks with horizontal scrollbars).

Comment: Can't you just add `word-wrap: break-word;` only on `<a>`s?

Comment: @Felix: That issue has nothing to do with links.

Comment: It seems to be back again... Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m.

Comment: @TLama Argh, my fault, side effect of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one/222376#222376); will fix. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @TLama Should be fixed in 3m48s.

Comment: @balpha, thanks! Will try tomorrow...

Answer (score 3):

I can repro this on Mac OS X 10.6.6 and Chrome 12. Interestingly enough when you go to edit a question it works.

Comment: Yup, noticed that, too. It's probably because the preview is generated from JavaScript and not loaded in-page.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this on Chrome 12.0.742.100 (Windows 7).